# How to install Windows on a Server without CD/DVR?

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation

How can I install Win Server 2008 on a single Dell F1D unit, rack mounted, no CD/DVD, BIOS Boot Devices: 1- SCSI drive (bare), 2-Network: IBA GE Slo. Nothing else on the Boot device list. Have USB ports, keyboard, monitor and NIC. No network at home. Can connect to internet via Xfinity (fixed IP) on a Win XP desktop. That's all I have.

Comment: Can you boot from flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount an external ISO image via the DRAC using the 'virtual media feature'.
This needs an DRAC5 with up to date firmware or newer. (Older firmwares resulted in confusing driver errors).

(This assumes your server has a DRAC card, but I can't imagine someone using a server without any ilo functions)

An alternative is to boot from USB. Basically use the same procedure for moving win7 install files to a USB pen drive:

```
Start an elevated cmd
diskpart
list volume
select volume 1   (make sure that the number used it the same as your pen drive)
clean
create partition primary
select partition 1
active
format fs=fat32
assign
exit
```

Then copy the files from the iso image or the DVD to the pen drive.

Comment: where it reads "list disk" should say "list volume", then "select volume x", where x is the USB volume. Other than that, perfect!

Comment: Fixed "disk" to "volume".